# Are "particle" and "partical" the same?

Tags: differences

Are *particle* and *partical* the same? When I check these two words in my dictionary at dict.cn, they look totally the same. Is there any difference or are they totally interchangable?

Comment: What's the name of the dictionary?

Comment: Oh, it's my English Chinese dictionary. The website is: Dict.cn

Comment: This is getting interesting now. When I check the word partical in some online Enlgish dictionary, such as dictionary.com and the freedictionary.com, I can not find the word 'partical' at all. So does that mean it doesn't exist?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because by any reasonable definition, ***partical*** isn't a "word" at all. It's just a misspelling.

Answer (score 10):

The OED, which is by most accounts the most definitive historical dictionary of English, has no entry for *partical*, nor is that given as any of the dozen alternative forms for *particle* (from *pertykyll* to *particul*). There are zero [British National Corpus results](http://bnc.bl.uk/saraWeb.php?qy=partical&mysubmit=Go) and zero [Corpus of Contemporary American English results](https://www.english-corpora.org/coca/).

There are certainly many instances of *partical* out on the Internet, for example in Google Books results. But leaving aside trade names, a great many of these appear to be editorial, typographical, or OCR errors. A book may mention *partical physics* or *partical board* on one page, but everywhere else refer to them as *particle physics* and *particle board*. In other cases, it appears to be a mistranscription of *[partial](http://query.nytimes.com/gst/abstract.html?res=9B04E7D91F31EE34BC4F51DFB1668382649FDE)*, *[practical](http://thechoice.blogs.nytimes.com/2012/03/09/author-suggests-higher-education-reforms-for-the-new-upper-class/?_r=0)*, or other similar words.

At the very least, writing *partical* when you intend *particle* is non-standard, and I would avoid it, and I would see about alerting your dictionary editors to the matter.

Comment: Thanks for your great answer. And thank you for your time.

Comment: This is genref.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Since OP indicated they looked in a dictionary, I felt it worth demonstrating that the dictionary was wrong— and demonstrating how to demonstrate it.

Comment: A good example of a mistake that may very well occur often in real life, but is still a mistake, where prescriptivists and descriptivists should agree.

Comment: Some people might have mistaken it for an adjective form of particle, i.e. partical size which is wrong as well explained above.

Comment: OP did not look into one of the recommended resources. You know very well you should have close-voted. This acceptance of questions that are arguably not appropriate for ELL does the site no favours.

Answer (score 1):

"Partical" is a common misspelling of "particle." The only online dictionary  with a definition for that spelling is urbandictonary.com.

How we spell particle comes down to the meaning derived from two suffixes: -icle and -ical.

> **From Oxford Dictionary:**
>
> > [Definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/-icle) of **-icle** in English: *suffix*
> >
> > > Forming nouns which were originally diminutives: *article* [or] *particle*
> >
> > [Definition](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/-ical) of **-ical** in English: *suffix*
> >
> > > Forming adjectives:
> > >       1. Corresponding to nouns or adjectives usually ending in -ic
> > >       2. Corresponding to nouns ending in *-y*

In this case, the reason English uses -icle is because particle means "a small or little part [of something]," in it most basic meaning. The -icle suffix shows specifically that a word is a noun/thing and in a diminutive/little form.

Since the -ical suffix indicates a word is an adjective form of something else, it doesn't make sense used with "part."

An example is the word "magic." When used as a [noun](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/magic), magic tells you *what* a thing is. With its [adjective](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/magical), "magical," it instead *describes* a thing as resembling to magic. Particles do not necessarily "resemble" other things, but it can be a minute piece of something larger, like in physics.

Since [Dict.cn](http://dict.cn/partical) shows the syllabificiation of "partical" as "par·ti·cle" when hovering over the word, their editors may not be aware English does not use with the -ical suffix with this word.